# Getting error fsockopen(): Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:389

Tags: php, owasp

I'm new to OWASP and mutillidae, while trying to access Mutillidae I'm getting this error. Please help to resolve this

> fsockopen(): Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:389 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)

```html
try{
        $lWaitTimeoutInSeconds = 2;
        if($fp = fsockopen($lDatabaseHost,$lDatabasePort,$lSocketErrorCode,$lSocketErrorMessage,$lWaitTimeoutInSeconds)){
            $lDatabasePortScanMessage = "The database is reachable. Connected to database host " . $lDatabaseHost . " on port " . $lDatabasePort;
        } else {
            $lDatabasePortScanMessage = "Cound not connect to database host $lDatabaseHost on port $lDatabasePort. The hostname or port may be incorrect, the server offline, the service is down, or a firewall is blocking the connection. $lSocketErrorCode - $lSocketErrorMessage";
        } // end if

        if (is_resource($fp)){
            fclose($fp);
        } // end if

    }catch (Exception $e){
```

Comment: This doesnt appear to be ZAP releated

Comment: This is a network issue configuration, or a timeout.